# What's the session option key for SQLAlchemy pool_size?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to increase the connection pool size when connecting from Python Flask application to MySQL. To start with, I got an error "TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached" so tried to increase the pool size by passing session_options as shown below. Now I get an error "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pool_size'". Any ideas on how I can increase the pool size?

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={'pool_size': 20})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE` configuration key: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html#configuration-keys

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 20
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: Didn't work. Getting an exception with this error message "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'"

Comment: it's not a session option. I added example in answer

Comment: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#configuration-keys

Answer (score 1):

The configuration key `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE` will be deprecated in version 3.0+ ([currently in development](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)).

Alternatively, you can config the pool size in the `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` configuration key.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'pool_size': 20,
}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: So in v3 does it default to infinity, or something else?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: For **v3** i don't find any informations. For **v2.x** it defaults to the engine’s default (usually 5) as mentioned in the [official docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/).